# Hypothesis testing on sampling from exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Problem:
Investigating the lifetime of some product, we're interested in testing the hypotheses
\begin{align}
 H_0: \mu=2\\
 H_1: \mu<2
\end{align}

Where $\mu$ is the expectation value of the lifetime in some arbitrary unit. We assume that the lifetimes follow an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
 f_X(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 \lambda e^{-\lambda x} &\text{ for }x\geq 0\\
 0      &\text{ ellers }
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and $E[X]=\mu=\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Now assume we have sampled the lifetime of 10 sample products and found a sample mean $\bar{X}$. Let $c>0$ be some number such that, if $W\geq c$ we accept the null hypothesis, otherwise discard it.

**Determine the number $c$ such that our test has signifiance level of 95%.**

**Solution (attempt)**

Our book mostly covers how to find the sigifiance intervals for Normal distributions, or cases of known mean with *n* large, which is hardly applicable for $n=10$, and the assignment asks for an *exact test of the nullhypothesis*.

I've only noted the following, that if $X_1,X_2,....X_n$ are indenpendent Exponential($\lambda$) stochastic variables, then their sum follows a Gamma distribution. I.e.
\begin{equation*}
 \bar{X}=\frac{X_1,X_2,...X_n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\sim \frac{1}{n}Gamma(n,\lambda) \sim Gamma(n,n\lambda)
\end{equation*}

That is, it follows some distribution
\begin{equation}
 f_Y(y) = \frac{(n\lambda)^n y^{n-1}e^{-n\lambda y}}{\Gamma(n)}, y>0
\end{equation}

But how does this help me determine $c$?

**P.S.**
The assignment problem also states that we might use the property:
For $X\sim Gamma(\alpha_1,\lambda), Y\sim Gamma(\alpha_2,\lambda) \implies X+Y\sim Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\lambda)$.

However, I'm not sure how to make use of this, as I don't see what is to be summed, any way.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis system can be rewritten as follows:

$$\begin{cases}
\mathcal{H}_0: &\lambda=\frac{1}{2} \\
\mathcal{H}_1: &\lambda>\frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}$$

Now let's fix  $\lambda'<\lambda''$ and derive the likelihood ratio:

$$\frac{L(\lambda'|\mathbf{x})}{L(\lambda''|\mathbf{x})}=\frac{(\lambda')^n e^{-\lambda'\Sigma x}}{(\lambda'')^n e^{-\lambda''\Sigma x}}=\Bigg(\frac{\lambda'}{\lambda''}\Bigg)^nExp(\lambda''-\lambda')\Sigma x$$

It is evident that this ratio is a monotone increasing function in $T=\Sigma x$

Now it is enough to apply a well known theorem on UMP test for families having a monotone likelihood ratio to derive the critical region, that in this case is

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[T<k|\lambda=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg]=\alpha$$

In your case, you know that

$$T=\Sigma x\sim Gamma(10;\frac{1}{2})=\chi_{(20)}^2$$

Thus you can easy solve your exercise using the [chi-square table](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html)

It results to me that we reject the Hypotheses that $\mu=2$ against the alternative that $\mu<2$ iff $\overline{X}_{10}<1.085$

---

The theorem I refer to is the following[image] taken from Mood Graybill Boes, Chapter IX, Tests of Hypotheses